# Redirect /blog to / in Amazon CloudFront and S3

Tags: amazon-s3, jekyll, amazon-cloudfront

My existing blog built on octopress served from VPS. It has a following path structure

http://blog.example.com/blog/2014/12/26/title-of-the-blog/

Now I moved to jekyll and deployed in S3 and CloudFront. New structure of my blog is

http://blog.example.com/2014/12/26/title-of-the-blog/

There is no `blog` in the url path. My old links already available in Social networking sites(twitter, facebook) and search engine. If any traffic come from old links, I want to redirect the links with `/blog/` prefix to `/`.

How can i do it in CloudFront or S3?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might solve your problem: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html. Although if blog is pretty large you might consider using API to generate these redirects